# Не мытьем, так катаньем

Tags: фразеология

Есть такая поговорка - "не мытьем, так катаньем", то есть, любым способом, "не так, так этак".
Интересно узнать, о чем изначально шла в поговорке речь? Какое мытье, мытье чего? И уж совершенно не понятно слово "катанье". И связь между этим самым мытьем и катаньем.
Буду благодарен за разъяснения.